# How to compare likelihood of models which produce very small or zero probabilites?

Tags: machine-learning, markov-process, likelihood

I am trying to compute likelihood scores to measure the relative predictive accuracy of different hyperparameterisations of a complex statistical model against a set of discrete data.

The model is a simulated Markov process with transitional probabilities estimated from data. For some states I have very little or no training data.

Because of this, when run on test data, the model occasionally produces zero or very small probabilities which either dominate the log likelihood or give it a value of negative infinity regardless of how well 99% of the other outcomes are predicted. What approach can I use to compare hyperparameterisations of the model which does not produce these unhelpful scores?

Comment: This is a sign the model is inappropriate (or, possibly, that the procedure used to fit it has failed).  How to cure that problem depends on the model.  Perhaps you could provide more details about it?

Comment: I added some clarification about the nature of the model to the question. Can you give more details about what you mean by "inappropriate"? The model is what it is and I would like to test it. Do you mean there are a set of properties that I must force the model to conform to make likelihood useful or do I need to change my method of validating it?

Comment: The most extreme example of an inappropriate model is one that does not allow for, or assigns zero probability to, one of your outcomes.  For instance, an age distribution model that assigns zero probability to being over 100 years old will produce problems like those you describe when there is anybody over 100 years old in the data.  Hyperparameters won't help: you have to make fundamental changes to the model (or else demonstrate the data are incorrect).

Comment: Perhaps your log likelihood takes a value of minus infinity because of numerical issues.  Look into the log-sum-exp trick for log-domain calculations, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LogSumExp

Comment: @whuber Suppose I make a model which predicts the probability of being a certain age simply by counting people of that age and dividing by the total population. The oldest person in the population is 100, but at some point they have a birthday and age to 101. The model still works very well for most purposes. (In fact even though the probability of being aged 101 is reported as 0, this is correct within a small epsilon) But now the likelihood score against the new data set is 0. Is there a standard approach to dealing with this that doesn't involve throwing out the model?

Comment: You seem to confuse a model with an estimate.  The model describes what is possible and provides probability distributions for the possibilities.  If the model simply will not allow for any chance that somebody is over 100 years old, and you observe a 101-year-old, then the model has been disproven--period.  You must throw out that model and replace it by one that, at the very least, is capable of ascribing some positive probability to what actually happens in the world.

Answer (score 0):

Compute relative predictive accuracy of each model with respect to the truth (y_label ~ (0, 1)).

y_pred_prob = max(10^-5, y_pred_prob)

Choose the model which has least cross-entropy =  - y_label * log(1 - Y_pred_prob_1) - (1-y_label) * log(Y_pred_prob).

In case of multi-class classification problem, use the multi-class logloss error which is the extension of the above.

It looks you are trying to tune the parameters that gives better accuracy for your model. There are various methods to reach those parameters efficiently. Look for strategies like randomsearch, gridsearch etc.

Comment: This function is still undefined if Y_pred_prob = 0

Comment: Y_pred_prob is the outcome of the model i.e. the predicted probabilities of your model.

Comment: My problem is that sometimes this is zero.

Comment: Don't make it absolute zero. Cap it at twice of double precision or at some value 10^-5 etc.